# Filter list values with a default fall-back option

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, append

Given 2 lists of numbers:

```
real_solutions_sols1 =  [-53.2909210236, -8.31658000998, 1.87689837129, 1.4]
real_solutions_sols2 =  [-21.1439685227, -19.2]
```

I would like the same code to rewrite the lists so that they contain numbers between `0.1` and `4.0`:

```
real_solutions_sols1 =  [ 1.87689837129, 1.4]
```

For the second list, this is not possible, so I would like the code to return the intact list:

```
real_solutions_sols2 =  [-21.1439685227, -19.2]
```

The following code works for `real_solutions_sols2`:

```
real_roots_zero_to_four = []
for i in real_solutions_sols2:
   if (i >= 0.1) and (i <= 4.0):
      real_roots_zero_to_four.append(i)
   else:
     real_roots_zero_to_four = real_solutions_sols2

print 'real_roots_zero_to_four = ', real_roots_zero_to_four
```

The `if` condition is not satisfied, so we jump to the `else` statement.

> real_roots_zero_to_four =  [-21.14396852, -19.2]

However, for the first list it is looping indefinitely:

```
real_roots_zero_to_four = []
for i in real_solutions_sols1:
   if (i >= 0.1) and (i <= 4.0):
      real_roots_zero_to_four.append(i)
   else:
     real_roots_zero_to_four = real_solutions_sols1

print 'real_roots_zero_to_four = ', real_roots_zero_to_four
```

I am not sure why this is happening

Comment: @ Nick A  Thanks for the comment. In my humble opinion, I think is not a duplicate with respect to those links, because as stated in the post, after replacing `&&` by `and`, the problem still appears. As has been correctly pointed out by Ev. Kounis,  this was a logical problem, which has been already edited in the title of the post.

Comment: thats perfectly fine, its just a possible duplicate rather than definite, ive since removed the comment, and you seem to have got a good answer so no harm done :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the following idiom\schema:

```
my_list = [x for x in my_list if 0.1 <= x <= 4] or my_list
```

What happens here is that we are taking advantage of the way the logical `or` works combined with the boolean nature of lists in Python.

In detail, assuming we have:

```
<exp 1> or <exp 2>
```

the Python interpreter will evaluate the *truthiness* of whatever is on the **left** of the `or` first. If that check returns `True`, `<exp 1>` is returned (**not** `True`). Otherwise, `<exp 2>` is returned regardless of its *truthiness* value which is not checked. Leveraging the fact that `bool([])` returns `False` we can be certain that if our list comprehension returns an empty list, the right side of the `or` will be returned (the original list `my_list`).

As a result, what we are doing is elegantly saying the following:

*Given `my_list`, get all its elements that satisfy the `if` condition unless there aren't any in which case just return the original one.*

---

The problem in your code was the use of `&` which **does not** mean `and` in Python. The logical `AND` is `and` so instead, you should be doing `if (i >= 0.1) and (i <= 4.0):`

Finally, note that in Python expressions like `i >= 0.1 and i <= 4.0` can be "condensed" into `0.1 <= i <= 4.0` (as you would write it in Math class).

Comment: Yep, definitely my favourite.

Comment: You might want to add a clarification about how in python `0.1 < x < 4` is a valid statement and how `&` and `and` are not the same thing

Comment: @Ev. Kounis Thank you for your answer. Your list comprehension approach is very elegant and I do really appreciate it. However, I am trying to understand why those `for` and `if` loops are not working: please note that if I substitute `&` by `and`, I still get an infinite loop. Could you please help me to understand where is the problem in the above code? Thanks again for all the effort

Comment: @DavidC.Because you are overwriting the `real_roots_zero_to_four` every time you meet a number that does not meet your criteria.. Do not know how else to explain this to you. Try to follow the code around, iteration by iteration and you will see for yourself.

Comment: @Ev. Kounis Ok, I see... I cannot come up to a better way of writing the above loop in a different way to avoid the problem - do you know how?

Comment: @DavidC. *Why does it have to be a for - loop?*

Comment: @Ev. Kounis  Well, I would say is a good way of looping over all the elements of the list

Comment: @DavidC.Well, it is not in this case but whatever. [Here you go](https://repl.it/repls/NovelUnfoldedChinchilla)

Comment: @Ev. Kounis Thank you very much for your comment and effort. My intention was not to disagree with you, but totally the opposite. I am trying to access the link but am I wrong if I am afraid it corresponds to something else?

Answer (score 2):

I  am just going to point out the reason for the infinite for loop its because when us assign `real_roots_zero_to_four = real_solutions_sols1`

You are doing a **shallow copy** it means the we are referring to the same copy of the variable ie  they are pointers that point to the same piece of memory

and then when you do

```
if (i >= 0.1) & (i <= 4.0):
     real_roots_zero_to_four.append(i)
```

you are appending to the  `real_roots_zero_to_four` and `real_solutions_sols1`

and then we are looping in the same location in the forloop

```
for i in real_solutions_sols1:
```

> Because they point to the same thing  and then we check the same
>   element and add it infinitely until the system crashes

In order to run the append on another list we must do a **deep copy**
which can be created using

```
real_roots_zero_to_four =list( real_solutions_sols1 )
```

Then there wont be anymore infinite forloops

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @Ev. Kounis is certainly the best solution for your problem. However I think it's interesting to see why your code does not work. The culprit is here:

```
real_roots_zero_to_four = real_solutions_sols1
```

When the `else` statement is satisfied, the above line is executed and the **reference** to `real_solutions_sols1` is **copied** inside `real_roots_zero_to_four`. From now on, all the values appended to `real_roots_zero_to_four` are appended to `real_solutions_sols1` too.

From here, the infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
result = [x for x in [-53.2909210236, -8.31658000998, 1.87689837129, 1.4] if x >= 0.1 and x <=4.0]
print(result)
# [1.87689837129, 1.4]
```

BTW, why do you use `&` as logical `AND`? This is how it is written in Python:

```
if i >= 0.1 and i <= 4.0:
```

Comment: Sorry, I do see that this (probably) solves the problem in the OP's code, but you might want to reword and explain *why* using `&` doesn't raise syntax errors but still gives the wrong answer

Comment: Correct, I've added a solution for the actual problem.